# How make li items in scrollable ul to take all width?

Tags: html, css

So basically I have a custom multiple select list which has `ul li` structure. The issue is that when selecting an element, it is being highlighted, but if you scroll to the right the highlighted part is not filling whole row.

One solution is to assign `display: table-row;` attribute to each `li` element, highlighted part fills whole row after that, but the issue is that after adding that rows start to not react when clicking on the white part, they respond only if you click directly on the text.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KRnxq/1/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/KRnxq/14/. Didn't like this way but it works :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the ul in a wrapper like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="files multiple-select MultipleSelectBox vertical" unselectable="on" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then put your box styles onto the wrapper and make the `ul` `display:table` like so:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    /* corner */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}

.MultipleSelectBox {
    display:table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/KRnxq/5/)

**EDIT**

Here is another version with the following fixes:

no black border creating a click effect when selecting items
better border radius so scrollbars don't remain square

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/KRnxq/17/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried that method before but forgot to re-initialize the list, now it works, there is only one minor issue - when you click on list it moves about 1px and creates impression of pressing the button. Is it possible to avoid that effect?

Answer (score -1):

you need to add **wrapper div** and put your UL-li in-the div

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and

```
.MultipleSelectBox {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    height: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: none;
}
```